# Overflow is shown mid css3 transition, how can I hide the overflow?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="service lorange">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="title two-lines"><span>P-Accelerator for Start-Ups</span></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.service .img {
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}
.service:hover .img {
    opacity:0
}
```

`.service` has a rounded border (35px) and `overflow: hidden;`.
This causes the inner `.title` to have its borders cut-off with its parent's borders (this is the expected behavior).

However, during the transition when hovering, and only mid-transition (since it starts and till it ends, not before or after it starts and finishes), the `.title` borders *do not* cut off for some reason.

Any idea what's going on?
I've tried making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KC4TH/), but it doesn't reproduce the issue. What property can be causing this?

**Edit:** The fiddle in its shell does not reproduce the problem, but [looking at the shell alone as a page **does**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KC4TH/show/) (I took the source of the iframe the fiddle uses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real reason this is happening is that browsers are only cropping the child element properly if it is not positioned (i.e. has `position:static;`). I've taken the liberty to alter your markup a bit and created a **[new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KC4TH/6/)** which works as it should on Chrome, Firefox and IE10 (also working on IE9 but without the transition ofcourse).

Markup:

```
<div class="serviceContainer"> <!-- added a container -->
    <div class="service lorange">
        <!-- removed div.img -->
        <div class="title two-lines"><span>P-Accelerator for Start-Ups</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS: (I've tried to include only the relevant CSS in the fiddle)

```
#services-grid .serviceContainer{ /* added a new container which the has the background image */
    background:url(http://foto.hrsstatic.com/fotos/0/3/256/256/80/FFFFFF/http%3A%2F%2Ffoto-origin.hrsstatic.com%2Ffoto%2F3%2F9%2F4%2F0%2F394033%2F394033_p_465430.jpg/zoKRL9Oq7JFnhFhhAn%2FfTQ%3D%3D/128,128/6/Catalonia_Yucatan_Beach-Quintana_Roo-Pool-394033.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    float:left;
    border-radius:35px;
    -moz-border-radius:35px;
    -webkit-border-radius:35px;
    -ms-border-radius:35px;
    margin:0 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#services-grid .service.lorange .title span{ /* Give background color only to the span */
    background-color:#efbd00;
}

#services-grid .service.lorange:hover{ /* fade color to container only when hovered */
    background:#efbd00;
}

#services-grid .service .title {
    position:static; /* This is what's doing the trick */
    padding-top:130px; /* position the span using padding instead of position:absolute */
    font-size:13pt;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The "`border-radius` on the child" solution is only a **cosmetic quickfix** which can cause inconsistencies and it's also causing little bumps on each side because of the radius difference:

[image: Weird bumps]

Comment: +1 Excellent Answer!.. Actually found the underlying problem!

Comment: @JustAnil Thanks mate :) I've had trouble with this behaviour in the past so I really got to the bottom of it..

Comment: Good job! I will get to applying this fix in a few hours when I'm back home, and if this works you've earned the bounty fair and square.

Comment: I can only assign the bounty tomorrow. Rejoice though, you will receive a double bounty! I couldn't select 150 again

Answer (score 4):

My solution: (But I am looking for a better one.)

```
#services-grid .service .title {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 130px;
   font-size: 13pt;
   text-align: center;
   height: 54px; /* IE fix */

   /* Add radius to bottom of .title */
   border-bottom-left-radius: 8px 15px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 8px 15px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/KC4TH/4/

Comment: That's an interesting solution, I however wanted to avoid setting the border radius for the title itself as it would be sort of a workaround more than a fix, and it wouldn't really get the problem itself solved. I would've resorted to that had my deadline been arrived with no solution.