# CSS3 Transitions on mouseout

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've created this fiddle. I'm sure you'll see my problem.

jsfiddle.net/vnbS3/

The box that pops up decides that it will not do the same on mouseout. I have tried a lot of things, and i don't think it is because of the z-index.

I think it is due to the transition on the .background, as i had to put a transition-delay to stop it messing up. However, the delay will not work on mouseout.

Comment: Read [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809923/overflow-is-shown-mid-css3-transition-how-can-i-hide-the-overflow/17863806#17863806). It covers the same case

Comment: I've read it, but i don't think the same applies. If you could replicate it in a fiddle, that would be awesome.

Comment: First - please post relevant code here and don't get around the rules with the non-live link.  Second - don't be sure that others will see what the problem is - **DESCRIBE* your problem so that others can understand what you are expecting and what is going wrong.  That also helps others searching for similar problems find this post and any answers it might have.

Comment: Perhaps this post will help: [Webkit not respecting overflow:hidden with border radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314207/webkit-not-respecting-overflowhidden-with-border-radius)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not helped.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of your ease transition in background it's causing it to have that weird popup delay.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnbS3/3/

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius: 999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I need the transition, as it moves my background image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an `!important` tag to the your `.background` div's `overflow:hidden` attribute

Here

http://jsfiddle.net/vnbS3/4/

Comment: This doesn't work. You have added !important AFTER the semi-colon, making the next line not work. This is the line that makes the background rotate.

Comment: My bad! It's 4.00 in the morning!

Anyways, if you're dead on with the transition, you will have to utilize a sibling selection - move the transitions away to a seperate subdiv and use a sibling selector to animate the hover takes place.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry.